# Convert array formatted strings to object

Tags: javascript

I got

```
[[["汽車","car","Qìchē",""]],[["名詞",["汽車","車","轎車","車輛","車廂"],[["汽車",["car","automobile","auto"],,0.26497361],["車",["car","vehicle","lathe","machine","rook","turn"],,0.21967085],["轎車",["car","bus"],,0.020115795],["車輛",["vehicle","car"],,0.013611027],["車廂",["car"],,0.0042828997]]]],"en",,[["汽車",[4],0,0,1000,0,1,0]],[["car",4,[["汽車",1000,0,0],["車",0,0,0],["轎車",0,0,0],["車輛",0,0,0],["車廂",0,0,0]],[[0,3]],"car"]],,,[["en"]],27]
```

this from google translator
However I tried

```
JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
```

It return an error Unexpected token

Comment: Before answering, what you posted here is _already_ parsed data, while JSON.parse expects a string (a quote delimited value).

Comment: Because It types is string

Comment: WHere is this data coming from? As one of tha answers said, it's not valid JSON because of `,,0.21967085`. If it's an API, you need to report the bug to them.

Comment: Two things to notice here. This is a _valid_ JS object (array, specifically), but not a valid _json_. That said, if this is a string then you should write it surrounded by quotes (just for clarity). Finally, if what you want is parse it to a _js_ (not json) object, then an eval(xhr.responseText). Eval should be always avoided, but i use it here for brevity.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that this string contains multiple commas making your json invalid.

You could try to replace it for a single one before parsing

```
var x = '[[["汽車","car","Qìchē",""]],[["名詞",["汽車","車","轎車","車輛","車廂"],[["汽車",["car","automobile","auto"],,0.26497361],["車",["car","vehicle","lathe","machine","rook","turn"],,0.21967085],["轎車",["car","bus"],,0.020115795],["車輛",["vehicle","car"],,0.013611027],["車廂",["car"],,0.0042828997]]]],"en",,[["汽車",[4],0,0,1000,0,1,0]],[["car",4,[["汽車",1000,0,0],["車",0,0,0],["轎車",0,0,0],["車輛",0,0,0],["車廂",0,0,0]],[[0,3]],"car"]],,,[["en"]],27]'
    .replace(/,{2,}/g, ",") // 2 or more replace for 1

JSON.parse(x);
```

Or if you have access to whatever is sending this string fix the output.

Comment: I think he said it's coming from Google Translate.

Answer (score 0):

First you should remove an extra `[]` brackets by replacing that.

ex,

```
[["汽車","car","Qìchē",""]]
```

should be:

```
["汽車","car","Qìchē",""]
```

EDIT: you can refer to this answer: [Parse Google Translate Json C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058250/parse-google-translate-json-c-sharp)

You should try:

```
var str = '[[["汽車","car","Qìchē",""]],[["名詞",["汽車","車","轎車","車輛","車廂"],[["汽車",["car","automobile","auto"],,0.26497361],["車",["car","vehicle","lathe","machine","rook","turn"],,0.21967085],["轎車",["car","bus"],,0.020115795],["車輛",["vehicle","car"],,0.013611027],["車廂",["car"],,0.0042828997]]]],"en",,[["汽車",[4],0,0,1000,0,1,0]],[["car",4,[["汽車",1000,0,0],["車",0,0,0],["轎車",0,0,0],["車輛",0,0,0],["車廂",0,0,0]],[[0,3]],"car"]],,,[["en"]],27]';

var objstr = $.parseJSON(str);
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with double brackets, it's just an array containing another array.